# Unslider (JS issue?) breaking on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh, unslider

So I've implemented Unslider (with adjustments to fade instead of slide) on my page, http://www.choiceid.ca

When I first bring up the page, the slider is often broken - it displays like 15 pixels tall instead of 700, and you can see the images rotating, like you're peeking over the top of a door.

If I hit refresh, it does nothing (or breaks it if it was working in the first place). If I go to the URL bar and hit enter again, or retype the address, it works correctly, but even that isn't reliable.

Any incite would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

must first images to load in order to properly create a slider. You have two options

1.Put unsilide in window .onload:

```
$( window ).load(function() {
   $('.banner').unslider();
});
```

2.manually enter the height of the slider in html

Comment: UGH finally! The height did it. The first option made them all show up onscreen at once, but second was great. Thanks so much!